# Slow folder opening due to folder scan in XFCE

Tags: xubuntu, directory, xfce, thunar

Is there a way to turn off background folder scan when opening a "Home" icon on XFCE desktop?
This takes time due to a lot of files in home folder (source repos, why not).

Answer (score 5):

I do following steps and it works for me:

- Open `/usr/share/gvfs/mounts/network.mount` this file using an editor: `sudo nano /usr/share/gvfs/mounts/network.mount`
- change AutoMount=true to AutoMount=false.
- Save file and login again.

This will stop `Thunar` stating the Network every time you run it.

Have a nice time.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, if your computer is up to date you can already speed up the first start up of Thunar by adding it to your startup applications.

In Session/Startup you can add a new app, call it Thunar maybe ;) and in the command field you can put `/usr/bin/thunar --daemon`so it will start in the background and be faster when you call a window.

Be careful not to "Save Session" on shutdown with this enabled, this will start a thunar for every-time you shutdown this way and will cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the thubmnail generator, tumbler. [what-is-tumblerd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89826/what-is-tumblerd)
I removed it from my install because it was causing folders I open to task the CPU, and delay because it is making thumbnails for every file.

How to remove:

**With Synaptic Package Manager:**
Search for `tumbler` click on the check box for it and select "Mark for Removal"

[image]

**With Terminal:**

```
sudo apt-get remove tumbler
```

*Note: Removing tumbler will ask you to remove `xubuntu-desktop` this is ok since it is a "meta-package" and will not remove xubuntu, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages*

Comment: How did you remove it? If I try to apt-get remove it, it tries to remove xubuntu-desktop package too. :|

Comment: yes, that is ok, xubuntu-desktop is a meta-package, http://askubuntu.com/questions/66257/what-is-the-difference-between-a-meta-package-and-a-package , you can remove it. "removing a meta package does NOT remove the packages it installed" , https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages