# Can I safely remove tumbler in Xubuntu 14.04?

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-environments, thumbnails

I have a similar problem to the one under this question: [What is tumblerd?](https://askubuntu.com/q/89826/47206)

That program is one of the most CPU hungry I ever seen in Xubuntu/Xfce. I do not really need thumbnails preview and I might just uninstall it.

```
sudo apt-get remove tumbler
```

But I get:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  tumbler xubuntu-desktop
```

Isn't that my desktop?

---

EDIT AFTER SOLVING THE MEMORY PROBLEM:

I would like to know the answer to this question, but considering the initial reason for removing tumbler: **removing tumbler is not necessary**.

The sudden memory use is related to video thumbnails, and that only for videos that are moved, downloaded etc.

To completely disable thumbnails, open a Thunar window, Edit-Preferences-Show thumbnails:Never.

To disable them for video files only, edit `/etc/xdg/tumbler/tumbler.rc` changing  the lines `Disabled=false` to `Disabled=true` under 'Video Thumbnailers' section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `xubuntu-desktop` is a dummy package that installs things that the Xubuntu desktop needs. If it would delete other packages those would have been listed too.
- [dependencies for tumbler](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/tumbler).

Feel free to remove that package.