# How do I remove Tumbler from Xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, xubuntu, dependencies, apt-cache

I want to remove the `tumbler` package from Xubuntu 16.04.

According to the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543494/can-i-safely-remove-tumbler-in-xubuntu-14-04), it can be safely removed from Xubuntu 14.04. The only package that depends on it is the meta-package `xubuntu-desktop`.

However in Xubuntu 16.04, I get this:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends tumbler
tumbler
Reverse Depends:
  tumbler-plugins-extra
  thunar
  xubuntu-desktop
  xfdesktop4
  ubuntustudio-desktop
  ristretto
  thunar
  rygel
```

So I can't remove it without also removing Thunar and Ristretto, which I don't want to remove.

Why do all these packages depend on `tumbler` in Xubuntu 16.04, but not in 14.04?

Comment: The additional dependencies usually occur when new functionality is added to those depending applications. For specifics, you are welcome to check the [changelogs](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com) on those packages. Feel free to look deeper  - maybe the dependency is *required*, maybe *recommends*. If the latter, the dependency can be excluded with a simple apt flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remove tumbler in the end.

Thunar and Ristretto only 'recommended' tumbler, and consequently removing tumbler didn't neccesitate removal of Thunar and Ristretto also.

Answer (score 1):

If this is about CPU cost, disabling thumbnails creation may do the trick
See this [Doc from xfce.org](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/tumbler)

1. Create a `tumbler.rc` file
2. Disable the plugin with `Disabled=true` for all thumbnailers
3. You can also play with `Priority` and `Locations` options